# Word that matches ^.*(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&]).*$

Tags: java, regex

I am totally confused right now.

What is a word that matches: `^.*(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&]).*$`

I tried at [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/) this `1Test@!`. However that does not work.

I really appreciate your input!

Comment: Would it be so much to ask why you need to find a string to match that regex? I'm really curious.

Comment: @Cruncher trying to understand how this works: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/guide/single.html#customization see last part where the password matches...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that your regex seems to be in **Java-flavor** (Note the `\\d`)

that is why you have to convert it to work with regex101 which does not work with jave (only works with php, phyton, javascript)

see converted regex:

```
 ^.*(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&]).*$
```

which will match your string `1Test@!`. Demo here: http://regex101.com/r/gE3iQ9

Comment: +1 However I would like to offer one minor nitpick.  It's not that the regexp is java flavor, it's that you are not looking at the regexp.  Setting a string with `String s="\\d";`, and then printing the string would output `\d`.  This distinction can be important because if the regexp is not specified in code, e.g. it's read from a file, then the extra slash would be erroneous.

Answer (score 1):

You just want something that matches that regex?

Here:

```
a1a!
```

Comment: @Kare This is an odd requirement, finding a string to match a regex. I'm really curious as to why

Comment: That string matches no better than OP's string.

Comment: Depends on which regex engine you run it. In Python, quotes wouldn't work so well unless they were escaped, but they are fine in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Your java string `^.*(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&]).*$` encodes the regexp expression `^.*(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&]).*$`.

This is because the `\` is an escape sequence.

The latter matches the string you specified.

If your original string was a regexp, rather than a java string, it would match strings such as `\dTest@!`

Also you should consider removing the first `.*`, doing so would make the regexp more efficient.  The reason is that regexp's by default are greedy.  So it will start by matching the whole string to the initial `.*`, the lookahead will then fail.  The regexp will backtrack, matchine the first `.*` to all but the last character, and will fail all but one of the loohaheads.  This will proceed until it hits a point where the different lookaheads succeed.  Dropping the first `.*`, putting the lookahead immidiately after the start of string anchor, will avoid this problem, and in this case the set of strings matched will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern matches

> \dTest@!

if u want a pattern which matches `1Test@!` try this pattern

> ^.*(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&]).*$